# Setting Liferay Tomcat Runtime

Tags: tomcat, liferay

I can't seem to change the runtime JRE on the Liferay Tomcat Runtime window.

I would like to change it to JRE 7 but It does save the changes. Has anyone faced this problem
in the past? How did you resolve this?

[image: Liferay Tomcat Server runtime]

Comment: Heads up warning tough JRE6 is the default target so you might run into problems by upgrading to JRE7. http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13360456

Comment: Liferay 6.0 may have problems with JRE7, go with the bundled JRE also as suggested by the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the JRE in `setenv.bat` (for Windows) or `setenv.sh` (for Linux) in tomcat folder of Liferay.